# C# - PInvokeStackImbalance - marshaling pointer to C struct

Tags: c#, c, dll, marshalling

I have following C code:

```
#define NAG_CALL __stdcall
#define NAG_DLL_EXPIMP __declspec(dllexport) 
#define MAX_TABLE_LEN 4096

struct section_for_csharp {      
  unsigned char new_data; 
  unsigned char end;    
  unsigned char stop;    
  unsigned char section[MAX_TABLE_LEN];
  unsigned int section_len;
  unsigned char table_id;
  unsigned int pid;
};
struct section_for_csharp data_to_ext;

NAG_DLL_EXPIMP void NAG_DLL_EXPIMP return_section_for_csharp (struct section_for_csharp *temp) {
  temp = &data_to_ext;
}
```

I have the following C# code:

```
    [DllImport("../../utils/libs_win/ts2sec.dll")]        
    public static extern void return_section_for_csharp(ref section_for_csharp temp);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct section_for_c_sharp
    {      
        public byte new_data;
        public byte end;   
        public byte stop;  

        //unsigned char section[MAX_TABLE_LEN];
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAX_TABLE_LEN)]
        public byte[] section;

        public uint section_len;
        public byte table_id;
        public uint pid;          
    };
```

When I run such a code:

```
section_for_c_sharp temp = new section_for_c_sharp();          
return_section_for_csharp(ref temp);
Console.WriteLine(temp.new_data);
```

I get on return_section_for_csharp function exection:
Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in 'C:\TSMuxer_CSharp\TSMuxer\bin\Debug\TSMuxer.vshost.exe'.

Additional information: A call to PInvoke function 'TSMuxer!TSMuxer.TSMuxer_MainForm::return_section_for_csharp' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Comment: There are several mistakes.  The NAGs certainly were a big mistake, typical for poorly named macro soup, you repeated NAG_DLL_EXPIMP twice.  Surely you meant to use NAG_CALL.  So the function is not actually CallingConvention.StdCall, that's why the debugger stepped in.   The function itself is very wrong, you don't actually copy the data at all, must be *temp = data_to_ext;  And the C# declaration requires the [Out] attribute on the argument so the pinvoke marshaller knows to copy this non-blittable struct back after the call.

Comment: Downvoter: you mind to explain?

Comment: Thanks. Works fine now.